# events.js:183 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event when giving yarn build

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

While giving the `yarn-build` command, this error was displayed:

> Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

### Try the below fixes . One of them will definitely work.

1. Try to close the process that is using your port.

   > **`netstat -tulnp | grep <port_number>`**
2. Installing the below pakcage fixed it for me forever.

   > **`npm install ws@3.3.2 --save-dev --save-exact`**
3. Run this command in your terminal :

   > `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

   **For Arch Linux add this line to /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf:**

   `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`

   Then execute:

   `sysctl --system`

   This will also persist across reboots.

   https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers#the-technical-details

Either one of the solutions will work . If not then restart your system and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Get same error:
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
I fix the problem by using different port number.
was:
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
changed to:
const port = process.env.PORT || 6000;

Hope will help some one.
**Or**
Get the PID using lsof

```
$ lsof -Pi | grep LISTEN
```

node      57096  (LISTEN)

then

$ kill -9 57096

run the server.